# Is it possible to upload an image to my server through a Facebook Application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I want to create a Facebook Application where the user can upload an image to my server. I would be glad if you can tell me if this is possible, if there are any restrictions, and what would be the best way to do it.

I would code the application with PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is some restriction about that on Facebook .Not sure,you might have to check out
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Also Best way would be to store images in Users album on Facebook using extended permissions ,instead of your server so it seems legitimate to both users and Facebook.

Though don't know what type of facebook application you are creating where you need to store images on server but it will not be a problem till you follow their privacy policy and terms.

And may be this app is something you might want to check ,its in beta and may be on same idea , and from that you can be sure 
http://usepipe.com

Comment: Well, their policy does not say anything about that. I will investigate more. I need to be sure.

Comment: @GilbertoRamos well i dont think that will be a problem, as its user will to upload image or not, so that wont be a problem.
Also a new app is in beta on same idea , and from that you can be sure
http://www.usepipe.com